# wkhtmltoimage not working on Polymer website

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, polymer-1.0, wkhtmltoimage

I'm trying to capture an image of a website using [wkhtmltoimage](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/). It is not working for webpages built using Polymer. For example,

```
wkhtmltoimage https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=google-web-components aaa.jpg
```

leaves me with a long white rectangle for an image. I am getting similar results with wkhtmltopdf.

How can I capture an image of a website built with Polymer?

Comment: I have tried with the **--javascript-delay 2000** option because I've seen that the web page had a delay before rendering. It usually helps, but not this time... :/

Comment: Again, it doesn't work because wkhtmltoimage does not support webcomponents, not because there is a delay in rendering (though that would also cause a similar problem if wkhtmltoimage *did* support webcomponents).

Comment: I too am having this problem, I've tried adding a delay of up to 10seconds, also tried enabling `debug-javascript` and `enable-javascript` but nothing seems to work.  It might help if I could somehow get the console from inside wkhtmltoimage to output, but I'm not having any luck.